# EasyOCR missing some text

Tags: python, easyocr

I'm just start using easyocr for text detection but I
found that some text were missing. For example this 1 and 2
per attached image.
[image: missin text]

I try to do the pre processing by dilate the text which is
not working. Also changing min_size to < 10 in readtext() also not
working.

Here is the code

```
import easyocr
import argparse
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('thin_image.jpg')

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en','th'])
results = reader.readtext(image,min_size=3)

for (bbox,text,prob) in results:
    (tl,tr,br,bl) = bbox
    tl = (int(tl[0]),int(tl[1]))
    tr = (int(tr[0]),int(tr[1]))
    br = (int(br[0]),int(br[1]))
    bl = (int(bl[0]),int(bl[1]))
    print(text)
    cv2.rectangle(image,tl,br,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imwrite("rs.jpg",image)
```

Could anyone point me to a correct direction please ?

Comment: OCR is a statistical process.  It is making a guess.  It is not perfect.

Comment: Is there anyway to increase a chance ? I think the text is big enough for detection.

Comment: OCR is generally intended for ordinary printed text, like in books. You should probably use a CV library for this.

Comment: Switched to paddleocr seem to working just fine.